# When using multiple waypoints, Google Maps will not show DirectionsStatus alert for "Not_Found"

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Thanks for any help you can provide on this one!

I'm using Google Maps API V3 to create a tool that lets the user enter a starting point, end point, and multiple waypoints. For an example of multiple waypoints, see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions#Waypoints

Sometimes, however, users enter a bad address or too many waypoints. People were getting upset that their map would not appear and they couldn't understand why. So, I built an alert system. For example, when the user puts in too many waypoints, they get an alert for the (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED), and so forth.

Here's the problem: when a users enters more than one waypoint, Google will not give me the alert for this status:

```
if(status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.NOT_FOUND){
alert("Error: One or more of your addresses was not found."); }
```

When I have ONLY one waypoint, the alert appears just find. Any ideas how I can fix this?

Comment: Do you have example addresses or locations that should cause the error but don't?

Comment: It appears to be a bug(at least it's not the expected result as described inside the documentation). You should [report it](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list).

Comment: Hi, @geocodezip. The bug occurs when there are multiple addresses in the waypoints. It doesn't seem to matter what those addresses are. When I use a start, end, and a single waypoint, the alert appears. When I use a start, end, and multiple waypoints, the alert does not appear.

Comment: Can you provide _one_ set of example addresses?

Comment: Sure! I use any gibberish address for Start and End. Then, I use one real address for the waypoint. I get the alert. If I put two addresses as Waypoints, though, I don't get an alert. Try this-- `Start: EYEYEYEYE   Waypoints: 350 5th Ave, New York, NY AND 1600 Pennsylvania Avenue, Washington, DC End: EYEYEYE `-- does that explain? Thanks, @geocodezip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you get a different response, ZERO_RESULTS, which you are ignoring.  You need to look at any status that is not OK.

[Example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_directions-waypoints_status.html)

Returns ZERO_RESULTS with 2 waypoints.  NOT_FOUND with one.  Both are errors.

Comment: Okay, so I found something strange. I had included each of these in my original version, in this order: MAX_WAYPOINTS_EXCEEDED, INVALID_REQUEST, NOT_FOUND, OVER-QUERY_LIMIT, UNKNOWN_ERROR, and ZERO_RESULTS . HOWEVER, when I change the order and move ZERO_RESULTS to the top of the order of status alerts, the alert does appear! Do you think there's a maximum number of alerts Google Maps will consider? Or some other glitch? Whatever it is, this is solved for me, and I appreciate you working through it.

Comment: That doesn't make sense.  Can you post the problematic code?  And perhaps a jsfiddle that exhibits this behavior?

Comment: I was going to post a variation of the code to test the behavior out, but I'm having serious trouble even getting that to show on the jsfiddle. Sorry! Here's what I've got so far. http://jsfiddle.net/kevindp78/9EvH7/ I was starting with the code you shared and then trying to edit it to show the issue, but for some reason, the map won't appear. No rush on this for my purposes since I'm full steam ahead with the project thanks to your input, but if you have advice on getting the map to display, I'll try to duplicate the error.

Answer (score 0):

set the `stopOver`-property of the waypoints to `false`

(this will fix the issue, but I'm not sure if it's suitable for your application)

Comment: Hmm. I don't think that will work because I want to show markers for each of my waypoints. Thanks, though!